# how to convert generics in java?

Tags: java, generics

What is the correct way to convert generics in java?

```
interface A {
}

class B implements A {

}

class C {
  public Set<B> returnSomeB(){
    //some logic
  }
}

C c = new C();
Set<A> = c.returnSomeB();
```

`Set<A> = c.returnSomeB();` this line would give me a compile time error, what's the most proper way to seamlessly convert this since class B is a concrete class of A interface?

Comment: Well, assuming this is your code, I see one immediate problem: Set<A> is just a type with no variable declaration.

Comment: Its compile time error because there no variable declaration       Set<A> = c.returnSomeB(); What are you assigning the value of  c.returnSomeB() to?

Comment: ok it was just a psuedo code I wrote from my mind without checking. Question was only about type checking

Answer (score 2):

A variable of type `Set<A>` can only hold a `Set<A>` object, not a `Set<B>`, even though `B` is a subtype of `A`.

The reason is this: What if you stored a `Set<B>` object in a `Set<A>` variable, then added an object of type `A` (but not `B`) to it? It would fit all the right argument types, but the end result would be a violation of Java's type safety.

To get around this, you can use wildcards. Instead of declaring a variable of type `Set<A>`, declare one of type `Set<? extends A>`.

Comment: ok tnx, so I assume I still should add cast declaration Set<A>  a = (Set<A>) c.returnSomeB(); like this right?

Comment: It depends. What are you actually going to _do_ with the value from `returnSomeB()`?

Comment: @gun-armod No, you should never cast to a generic type like `(Set<A>)`. That's why the compiler gives you a type safety warning about this.

Comment: @erickson The circumstances when it's appropriate to cast to a generic type are similar to those when it's appropriate to cast to a non-generic one. That is, it's to be avoided, but sometimes you don't have a choice.

Comment: No, Taymon, it's very different. When you cast to `(Set<A>)`, the operand is only verified as being of type `Set`. If it's not a `Set`, a runtime exception will be raised immediately at that point in the code. However, no checking is done for the generic type parameter, `<A>`. If the set contains objects of some other type, a `ClassCastException` will be raised at some later time in some other place, with no connection to the offending code. That's why the compiler warns about this invalid cast.

Answer (score 0):

Try bounding your type parameter to the widest possible scope of acceptable values:

```
interface A {
}

interface B extends A {
}

class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Set<A> foo = C.returnSomeB();
        final Set<B> bar = C.returnSomeB(); 
    }

    public static <T extends A> Set<T> returnSomeB() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: `super B`, I think (is that legal, I always forget).